# How to control volumes of file playing using System Sound Services by side volume control buttons in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have woprking on an  app in which i have played sound file using system sound but the volume of playing sound file is not adjusting according to side volume control buttons. Even i set the volume 0 from side button it still sounds. I can also use `AVAudioPlayer` but in my app i am dawing on the surface and while drawing it plays volume if i use `AVAudioPlayer` it effects the drawing. Can any one tell me how can i adjust volume using system sound in iOS.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code for control system sound,it not work in simulator,only work in device

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];//set values 0-1
```

Comment: AvAudioPalyer and MPMoviePlayer create flaw on drawing that's why iam not using this.I can't find any solution which adjust system sound audio by volume button on side